# Windows Defender alerts "Exploit:JS/Blacole.KU" for ext-modern-debug.js

Tags: extjs

Windows Defender alerts "Exploit:JS/Blacole.KU" for ext-modern-debug.js in versions 7.6.0 and 7.5.1. I also did a scan for versions 6.5.2 and the exploit was found. The exploit is not found in version 6.0.0.

Can anyone tell what the reason is?

Microsoft gives this information about the exploit:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?name=Exploit%3AJS%2FBlacole.KU&threatid=2147678616

Unfortunately Windows Defender is not giving the line or any further information why it alerts this exploit.

Comment: Getting the same. On VirusTotal only Microsoft and Rising flag this finding for the file.

Comment: Same here since today, i raised a ticket at Sencha support. No answer yet.

Comment: Official Answer from Sencha: They are aware and put this to high priority.

Comment: Thank you @Marco'Lubber'Wienkoop.

After the last update WD does not find the Exploit anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got fixed with the latest update of WD , it seems to be an issue from the Microsoft end.

Comment: I agree with this

Answer (score 1):

Same here. It did remove an modern-all-debug.js in an old Ext JS 7.4 folder so I suspect a recent WD update to signal a false positive. Either that, or we're all distributing exploits with Sencha projects for years now :)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the same is true for for the 7.2.0.66 version of the framework.